# How to use SUMIF to generate a blank if criteria is not met

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs, excel-2019

I am trying to work out average profit per day. The below formula works, however, if there is not data for a month then I would like it to return a blank, NOT a `0` as it is currently.

Current formula :

`=SUMIFS('SHARES LOG'!L:L,'SHARES LOG'!P:P,">="&DATE(2021,2,1),'SHARES LOG'!P:P,"<="&DATE(2021,2,28))/28`

Could anyone change this for me to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: Can you wrap it within an IF formula. If(no data for month),"",your formula)

Answer (score 0):

What @Isolated mention in comment you need `IF()` function to do that. Try-

```
=IF(=SUMIFS('SHARES LOG'!L:L,'SHARES LOG'!P:P,">="&DATE(2021,2,1),'SHARES LOG'!P:P,"<="&DATE(2021,2,28))/28=0,"",=SUMIFS('SHARES LOG'!L:L,'SHARES LOG'!P:P,">="&DATE(2021,2,1),'SHARES LOG'!P:P,"<="&DATE(2021,2,28))/28)
```

You can also apply format to result cells to hide `0` zero from cells. Apply `0;-0;;@` to custom format. Microsoft article to [Display or hide zero values.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/display-or-hide-zero-values-3ec7a433-46b8-4516-8085-a00e9e476b03#:%7E:text=Hide%20zero%20values%20in%20selected%20cells&text=Select%20the%20cells%20that%20contain,%40%2C%20and%20then%20click%20OK.)

[image]

Comment: Hi Harun, thanks for this, although when entered the error "there's a problem with this formula". I have tried to fault find however I cannot see the issue.